# Error al instalar una extension en magento2

Tags: php, magento2

Estoy desarrollando una extensión para magento2 pero al intentar instalarla en mi servidor para realizar pruebas me aparece el siguiente error:

> **Constant name is expected**

Verificando el logs de nginx obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

> **PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Constant name is expected. in .../magento2-2.2.2/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Constant.php:24**

Según este archivo veo que no encuentra una clase que defino en el archivo `/etc/di`.

```
<virtualType name="TestPaymentsConfig" type="Magento\Payment\Gateway\Config\Config">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="methodCode" xsi:type="const">\Test\Payments\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider::CODE</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Para la instalación subo la extensión en `app/code/Magento` y la instalo desde el **Module Manager**, creo que composer no esta registrando el namespace de la extensión y por eso el error, bueno tampoco tengo la extensión en un repositorio de github solo en mi local.

Comment: Desde el Module Manager no se pueden instalar extensiones, ¿tal vez te refieres al Extension Manager?

Comment: Lo que hice fue crear un repositorio y la instale desde composer.

Answer (score -1):

En mi caso, el error era un problema de mayúsculas y minúsculas en la ruta de la clase que tenía el valor de la constante.

En Windows, la ruta funcionaba bien porque los nombres de las carpetas no distinguen entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, pero luego cuando lo llevé a Linux no funcionó ya que no se encontraba el nombre de la carpeta (porque los nombres de carpetas son sensibles a mayúsculas y minúsculas en este entorno).

Comment: En español por favor

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow in Spanish. Remember that you must write in Spanish.